# Functions inside componentDidMount are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following block of code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      avatar: '',
      ...some more data...
      }

      this.fetchUser = this.fetchUser.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBox onSubmit={this.fetchUser}/>
        <Card data={this.state} />
        <BaseMap center={this.state.address}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    function fetchUser(username) {
      let url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;

      this.fetchApi(url);
    };

    function fetchApi(url) {
      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
           .... some data that is being fetched .... 
        });
      };

    let url = `https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.username}`;
  }
}

export default App;
```

However, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` for the following line: `this.fetchUser = this.fetchUser.bind(this);` in the `constructor` where I bind the function to `this`.

How can I make the function, which is inside `componentDidMount` method, visible and available for binding?

EDIT:

The reason I'm putting the functions inside `componentDidMount` was because of a suggestion from another user on StackOverflow. He suggested that:

> @BirdMars that because you don't really fetch the data in the parent,
> and the state doesn't really hold the address object. call the fetch in
> componentDidMount of the parent and update the state there. this will
> trigger a second render that will pass in the new state with the
> address object (the first render will be with an empty state.address
> of course until you finish the fetch and update the state)

Comment: Any reason why are you not putting `fetchUser` and `fetchApi` outside `componentDidMount`?

Comment: @BirdMars you can call those functions in `componentDidMount` but define them outside.

Comment: Why not move the functions outside of the `componentDidMount` or not use functions at all?

Comment: `call the fetch in componentDidMount` does not mean you declare them inside.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is some fundamental misunderstanding here, you can still *call* the functions inside `componentDidMount`, however you should not *define* them inside it.

Simply define the functions outside `componentDidMount` and this will solve your problems, here is a short example

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.fetchUser(this.state.username);
}

function fetchUser(username) {
   let url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;
   this.fetchApi(url);
};

function fetchApi(url) {
   fetch(url)
   .then((res) => res.json())
      .... some data that is being fetched .... 
   });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Its a simple matter of scope:

```
function outer(){
  function inner(){
  }
}
inner(); // error does not exist
```

As birdmars suggested you should call `this.fetchUser()` inside component did mount. but declare the function outside!

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBox onSubmit={this.fetchUser}/>
        <Card data={this.state} />
        <BaseMap center={this.state.address}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
  fetchUser(username) {
      let url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;

      this.fetchApi(url);
    };

  fetchApi(url) {
      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
           .... some data that is being fetched .... 
        });
      };
  componentDidMount() {
    let url = username; //frome somewhere, most probably props then use props Changed function instead!
    var user = his.fetchUser(url)
    this.setState(() => {user: user});

  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the functions inside componentDidMount they are only visible in that scope and get be accessed by the component itself. Declare them in your component.
What he was talking about in this post was to call the functions from componentDidMount, but not to declare them in there.

Answer (score 0):

"Another guy from StackOverflow" suggest you to **call** functions in `componentDidMount()` method, but not to define them there.

So you should do this instead

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        ...
        this.fetchUser = this.fetchUser.bind(this);
        this.fetchApi= this.fetchApi.bind(this);
    }
    ...
    fetchUser(username) {...}
    fetchApi(url) {...}

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchUser(...);
        ...
    }
}
```